# AFNetworking setImageWithURLRequest not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am unable to download the images, The `setImageWithURLRequest` method is not going inside the success/failure block. Please someone advise me how solve this task. This is my code.

```
__weak UIImageView *images ;


 NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",imageBaseUrl,eachImage];
            NSLog(@"image download url %@",url);
            [images setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]
                                         placeholderImage:nil
                                                  success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                                      if(response){
                                                          [arr addObject:image];
                                                          NSLog(@"Success fetching image");
                                                      }else{
                                                          NSLog(@"The image data is not there");
                                                      }
                                                  } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                      NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@", error);
                                                  }];
```

Comment: Please give sample image URL

Comment: @HiteshSurani, thank you for responsing, http://3.0.191.16/uploads/patient/2133/38049.jpg This is my image url

Answer (score 0):

I have checked above code and it is worked for other image URL. While i am used your image URL it is failed to load image.

if you add manually **http://** to URL. Then image is load properly.

Your URL should be like http://3.0.191.16/uploads/patient/2133/38049.jpg

Your logic should be like below.

if url doesn't contain `http` then append **http://** manually otherwise go with url from server.

Or you can ask API developer to send proper image URL.

Please mark as accept if it will work for you.